# Is there a better way to play ambient sounds in sprite kit iOS 10 Xcode 8 than this?

Tags: objective-c, audio, sprite-kit, xcode8, ios10

I have a method for playing an ambient sound in a sprite kit based game, but I'm wondering if there is a better method.  I've seen the ambient sound function in the type ahead, but it seems to be something used by the framework and not something for users of the framework.

Here is what I am currently doing

```
- (void) playAmbientSound {

    [self runAction:self.pAmbientSound completion:^{
        [self playAmbientSound];
    }];
}



- (void) initSounds {
    // Avatar swim sound
    self.pSwimSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"swim-sound.m4a" waitForCompletion:NO];

    // Animation sound
    self.pAmbientSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"ambient-final.mp3" waitForCompletion:YES];
    // Do the Sound in a loop
    [self playAmbientSound];

}
```

Comment: Better use AVAudioPlayer for ambient sounds.

Comment: there is another point about file extension, i read that some extension are not playing with AVAudioPlayer like .m4a .give a try to different extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SKAudioNode` is the best way to get ambient audio in your game.  It is built on top of `AVFoundation`, and can be used with `SKAction`s to change the volume of the sound or offer a 3d positional sound.  Also `SKScene` has an `audioEngine` property which is of type `AVAudioEngine`.  This will allow you to manage all of your audio nodes at once for situatuions where you need to stop all audio or change the overall volume of everything.

Answer (score 3):

You can use  AVAudioPlayer.

the sample in Objective-C:

Add the `audioPlayer` in your `.h`  file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

then in your `.m` file use it like this:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/background.mp3",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
_audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite
[_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[_audioPlayer play];
```

And in Swift 3 is like this:

```
 func playMusic() {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "background", ofType: "mp3")
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print("error play music")
    }
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1 //Infinite
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

for infinite loop playing you need to set  numberOfLoops equal to -1